# WPF CommandParametr

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

привет есть список

```
<ListBox Name="item">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Name}">

                </TextBlock>
                <TextBox Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="18" Name="Count"></TextBox>
                <Button Content="Заказать" Margin="10,0,0,0" Tag="{Binding Path=Id}"
                        Command="{Binding Query, Source={StaticResource View}}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Id}">
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Ну так вот мне нада я команду передать 2 параметра Id который сейчас забинжен и текст из TextBox
Как это сделать подскажите.

Comment: Используйте MultiBinding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350598/passing-two-command-parameters-using-a-wpf-binding

Comment: @maxwell: Почему не как ответ?

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать MultiBinding:

```
<Button Content="Zoom" Command="{Binding MyViewModel.ZoomCommand">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourConverter}">
             <Binding Path="Width" ElementName="MyCanvas"/>
             <Binding Path="Height" ElementName="MyCanvas"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Конвертер:

```
public class YourConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, ...)
    {
        return values.Clone();
    }

    ...
}
```

Затем можно обращаться к передаваемым параметрам следующим образом:

```
public void OnExecute(object parameter)
{
    var values = (object[])parameter;
    var width = (double)values[0];
    var height = (double)values[1];
}
```

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1350995/6641468)